# How can I send FormData using XmlHttpRequest and map to viewmodel properties

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send some values in a FormData object using XmlHttpRequest to a Controller. The thing is when I do this locally (localhost) the data is mapped to the properties of the ViewModel correctly and everything works fine.
When I try to this on our production environment it seems that the values are not mapped to the ViewModel.(Post happens on same url) 
- Could there be any security check that I don't know about? 
- Does anyone have any advice what to do or where to look?

```
JS:
var payload = new FormData();
payload.append('TestTitle', $('#TestTitle').text());
payload.append('TestId', $('#TestId').val());
payload.append('TestGuid', $('#TestGuid').val());

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onStateChange);
xhr.open('POST', '/test/savetest?rand=' + Math.random());
xhr.send(payload);

------
C#:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveTest(TestViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       //do stuff
   }
   return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found out that the POST was being blocked due to security settings.

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution :

```
JS:

    var payload = new FormData();
    payload.append('TestTitle', $('#TestTitle').text());
    payload.append('TestId', $('#TestId').val());
    payload.append('TestGuid', $('#TestGuid').val());

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onStateChange);
    xhr.open('POST', '/test/savetest?rand=' + Math.random(),false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(payload);

    ------
    C#:
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveTest(TestViewModel model)
    {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           //do stuff
       }
       return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately this solution also didn't work on my localhost. (ViewModel had only default values)

Comment: Try to use jQuery.ajax instead of XMLhttpRequest